# numpy filter across dimensions for specific values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to filter an image with shape `(224, 224, 3)` in RGB which has been loaded into a `numpy` array, where the last axis is the channels.

The logic is simple: look for specific pixel values across the 3 channels and assign a label to a new 1-Dim/1-Channel array. This is used for Segmentation Networks, where a pixel-wise label is assigned to represent the area of the object in the image.

The current loop looks like this:

```
mask     = Image.open(args.input).convert('RGB')
array    = np.array(img_mask)

h, w, c = array.shape
bg = np.zeros((w, h))
fg = np.zeros((w, h))

for i in range(0, h):
    for k in range(0, w):
        if np.array_equal(array[i,k], [0, 0, 0]):
            bg[i,k] = 1
        elif np.array_equal(array[i,k], [255, 200, 0]):
            fg[i,k] = 2

label = np.stack((bg, fg), axis=0)
```

This produces a `(2, 224, 224)` where `axis = 0` is the channels and then `axis=1` has the pixel labels.

I have tried to replace the two `for` loops using `np.where` however, the result is still a 3D array, whereas what I want is a 1D array, created for each pixel coordinate which matches the condition:

```
bg    = np.where(array == [0, 0, 0],     1, 0)
fg    = np.where(array == [255, 200, 0], 2, 0)
label = np.stack((bg, fg), axis=0)
```

However here I get: `(2, 224, 224, 3)`

The current `for` loop implementation is painfully slow, and I suspect this can be done using built-in `numpy` functions, but I've failed to achieve the same result so far.

Comment: Did you try an intermediate solution : first reshape in (224x224, 3) with native numpy function (C speed), then use where on the last dimension, then reshape again.? Personnaly I'm  not a big fan of too many dimensions array, it's always create a lot of problems.

Comment: @GuilhemL. No I didn't because depending on the channel colors I'd have to be careful which dimensions I'm reducing? Unless I've not understood this well; if the same values are broadcast across all 3 axes, then I could just reduce/remove to only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you can use `select` for masking, and `ravel` to get `1-D` array:

```
array = np.array([[[0,0,0],[128,128,128]],
                  [[128,128,128],[255,255,0]]
                 ])

label = np.select([(array==(0,0,0)).all(-1),      # all make sure all channels are identical
                   (array==(255,255,0)).all(-1)],
                  [1,2], 0)

print(label.ravel())
```

Output:

```
array([1, 0, 0, 2])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite? E.g., where the condition doesn't match, to select.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, wouldn't `array != (0,0,0)` work?

Comment: or use the default (`0` here), if you just want to select everything that doesn't match the other queries.

Comment: yes, so I suppose it would be `label = np.select([(array==(0,0,0)).all(-1),((array!=(0,0,0)).all(-1)], [1,2], 0)` ?

Comment: You need `.any(-1)` if you want things that don't match exactly.  Anything with 0 for any channel won't be selected there.

Comment: @Ælex I don't think so. Basically, the command `np.select` check the first condition `array==(0,0,0)`, if true, then the position is `1`, else, it check `array==(255,255,0)`, if true, it is `2`, else it takes the default value `0`. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, I was just wondering if I could do the reverse, e.g., set to 1 if RGB is zero, else set to 2. Bizarelly the result is `(224, 224)` and not `(2, 224, 224)`, however I've extracted them one at a time: `bg = np.select([(array==(0, 0, 0)).all(-1)], [1], 0)` and `fg = np.select([(array!=(0, 0, 0)).all(-1)], [2], 0)` and then stacked them, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Oh, in that case, `np.where` like you did would be good. All you missed was `.all(-1)`.

Comment: So how would you do that? Add `.all(-1)` at the end of the condition?

Comment: Yes, either at assignment of `fg` or of `label`.

Comment: I'm getting the same dimensions but different data, but you have more than answered my question, so thank you very much!!!